# How can I customize Angular Material Sidenav Component?

Tags: css, angular, nav, angular-material2

I am building a chat using Angular 4 and Angular Material and I am trying to display some information on a sidenav. I am using sidenav from Angular Material, but I am willing to customize the styling and to get rid of the shadow that appears when the sidenav is open.
[image: The image below depicts the problem]

In the styles.css file I tried this:

```
.mat-sidenav-transition .mat-sidenav-backdrop.mat-sidenav-shown {
    transition: background-color .4s cubic-bezier(.01,.1,.25,1); 
    background-color: transparent;

}
.mat-sidenav-backdrop.mat-sidenav-shown {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I also tried to use `::ng-deep`  but it won't work.

Comment: I am not sure if the docs had this information when you submitted this question but this is documented now. Here's a link to the examples section, which demonstrates all of the options the sidenav component has. You should check that out before you attempt to customize it on your own.

https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mode="side"`, which does not create a backdrop.

```
<md-sidenav mode="side" opened="true">Drawer content</md-sidenav>
```

see [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview)

Comment: Thank you! This is actually what I wanted. And even the content looks better this way because it is not pushed and hidden. Thank you !!!